# Error while running nodemon-The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am new to node.js and I am unable to install and run nodeman in my VS studio. I have installed t globally using command **npm install -g nodemon** and then added the path in both User and System env variables . Got path using command -> **npm config get prefix**
I dont know what point I am missing .
[image]

Error Log:

```
The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and intalling it again? Also please check your path where you installed it.

Comment: @Bhavy shouldn't  we need to copy the result of this command in path -> npm config get prefix  ?

Comment: @Bhavy uninstalling and installing does not work for me. Still same error nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ nodemon -v
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the first path in path variables (in Environment Variables) is NPM path.

Comment: You mean before SystemRoot paths also ?

Comment: yes .make it the first one and it should work